Write a message to queue instead of address
I have an use case where we need to write a messages to durable/non durable queues instead of an address in AMQ broker. We don't want to write the messages to be sent address and route to respective queues of an address. Can this be done using Java?

If you want to send a message directly to a queue rather than sending the message to an address and letting the broker route it to the proper queue(s) then you should use the fully qualified queue name (i.e. FQQN). If you had the queue myQueue on the address myAddress then you'd send your message to myAddress::myQueue.
You can do this from any protocol and any supported client - including Java.
